# Magento 1.9 Customers can't update their info on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.9.2.0

anyone knows the reason why clients can't save any updates on the frontend?

When they add a new address or change password or any account info, after clicking save button it will redirect back to the previous page which is with nothing changed.

My Magento version is 1.9.2.0.

Updates:

I've tried the most common solution which is adding form_key in customer page but not working.

And occasionally I found when disabling "Use Web Server Rewrites" in setting → Web → Search Engines Optimization can solve this problem but I need web server rewrites this function for SEO purpose. What should I do if I want to fix this problem while enabling "Use Web Server Rewrites"?

Comment: Did you get any error in var/log or console?

Comment: Check `form_key` in customer  form .

Comment: Tried but not working... Maybe it's related to "Use Web Server Rewrites" this function

Answer (score 0):

The affected forms could be missing a **form_key** field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've tried it but not working... Maybe it's related to "Use Web Server Rewrites" this function. Any other possible solutions?